# Create SNS Topic As Cognito Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

Playing around with AWS in Golang.

At the moment I use the AWS SDK front-end with Facebook as a Credentials Provider to create Identities in AWS Cognito. This works great.

I use SNS to send Push Notifications to iOS and Android, this also works great.

But I read that SNS only allows 3000 topics per User. If I understand how Cognito and SNS work (and with what I see in logs/dashboard) All Topics are created by the Role that the Cognito Identities assume. So they are all created by the same "User". So I will hit 3000 very quickly with the service in mind.

Ideally I would send AWS Credentials to my Golang back-end and there I would create Topics per Identity and confirm subscriptions.

Is it possible to create Topics per Cognito Identity, make the individual Identities the Owner of the Topic?

If so, is this a specific API call?

Or is this something that has to be set with a specific Role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS doesn't typically limit things by "user" like that. The 3,000 SNS topics limit is per AWS account. This is a soft limit. You can fill out a request to have the limit raised.

Also, I'm not sure 3,000 is the default limit anymore. I can't seem to find that in any of the official documentation at this time. This is the only thing I can find, which lists a limit of 100,000 SNS topics: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_sns

Comment: I like what you are saying!